# Rewrite $y = \cos(t) - \sin(t)$ to $y = A\cos(\omega t - \phi)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I'm really lost here..
The subject is differential equations, but I seemed to have missed this part in class.
How do I convert to only $\cos$?

$$y = \cos(t) - \sin(t) \rightarrow y = A\cos(\omega t - \phi)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A\cos(\omega t-\phi)=A\cos\omega t\cos\phi+A\sin\omega t\sin\phi.$$

Then by identification when $\omega=1$,

$$
A\cos\phi=1,\\
A\sin\phi=-1.$$

Solve for $A$ and $\phi$. (Hint: take the sum of squares and take the ratio.)

Answer (score 0):

use $$\cos(t)-\sin(t)=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-t\right)$$

Comment: Fits like a glove, I think i understand how you got the $\sqrt{2}$, but not the inside of sinus

Comment: this comes from $$\frac{\pi}{4}$$ if you use the addition formulas